# Aligning DIVs/Classes Top-Down

Tags: html, css

I'm just starting to get into HTML, and for a project in Introduction to Computer Science, I need to make a web page.  I have a concept and I know what I want to do, but I can't figure out how to get this right.  So far, I have this:

```
<!DOCTYPE hmtl>
<hmtl>
  <title>
    Audiophile Poll - M100s or Mad Dogs v3.2?
  </title>
  <head>
    <style>
      body{
        background-color: #292E37;
      }
      h1{
        width: 100%;
        color: #800000;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: "Lucida Console", "Courier New";
        font-size: 40px;
      }
      .heading{
        color: #808080;
        text-align: left;
        margin: 5px;
        font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode";
        font-size: 24px;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
      .body{
        width: 100%;
        font-weight: normal;
      }
      .image{
        float: left;
      }
      .paragraph{
        color: #808080;
        font-size: 14px;
        width: 60%;
        float: left;
        margin: 10px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>
    <b>
      V-MODA M-100 vs. MrSpeakers Mad Dog
    </b>
    </h1>
    <div id="box1">
      <div class="heading">
        V-MODA M-100
      </div>
      <div class="body">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="http://www.acgears.com/images/m_100_shadow_laying_case_square_web.jpg" height="300px" width="300px"/>
        </div>
        <div class="paragraph">
          <b>Cost:</b> $310<br />
          <b>Audio Profile:</b> "Modiophile" (near balance with light emphasis on bass)<br />

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>  
    <div id="box2">
      <div class="heading">
        MrSpeakers Mad Dogs v3.2
      </div>
      <div class="body">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="http://cdn.head-fi.org/0/05/300x300px-LS-0512aba0_1125220115_maddog.jpeg" height="300px" width="300px"/>
        </div>
        <div class="paragraph">
          <b>Cost:</b> <br />
          <b>Audio Profile:</b> <br />

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now, I'm gonna expand the text inside, but that's it.  I have the first set of object (the first heading,image and paragraph) aligned right,but whenever I try loading the second set,I get an odd alignment.  What do I need to so that I can get something like this:

HEADING1

IMAGE    TEXT

-BREAK-

HEADING2

IMAGE    TEXT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Add this line between two div's

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/25RSE/)

Comment: You are awesome.  Thank you very much.  I had a feeling this line was involved, but I wasn't sure where, as someone else left it right before a '</div>' tag for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

add this div between both the box. This will solve your alignment problem

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I was AFK,so I'm glad to see this worked, even though the demo from Sridhar was a good proof of concept.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add

```
<!--box 1 ends-->
<br style="clear:both;"/>
<!--box 2 starts-->
```